# CREATE_FAILED : Flavor's local disks conflict. You need to create a bootable volume to use this flavor for your instance

Tags: openstack, volume, openstack-nova, openstack-heat, bootable

As I'm trying to create a stack, I get the following error :

```
[kypo-proxy-jump-stack]: CREATE_FAILED  Resource CREATE failed: 
Forbidden: resources.kypo-proxy-jump: Flavor's local disks conflict. 
You need to create a bootable volume to use this flavor for your instance. (HTTP 403)
```

I already tried to boot instance from image and attach non-bootable volume, as given in the link below : https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/user-guide/cli-nova-launch-instance-from-volume.html
but it didn't work.

Comment: What's the flavor info? Could you provide the `openstack flavor show` result? Maybe you have something wrong with flavor's `Disk or Ephemeral`  setting.

Comment: Or maybe you should try this guide **Create a volume from an image and boot an instance from that volume** which in your link. Please add more info by which command will occur the `following error`, and what's the **error output** for `but it didn't work`.

Comment: @VictorLee thank you. When i give openstack flavor show <flavor> i get a lot of ..... Text without any information on the inside.  The error occurs when i give the following command :    ./create-base.sh    . It is the second step of Deployment in the follwing link : https://docs.crp.kypo.muni.cz/installation-guide/base-infrastructure/

Comment: sorry, I can't figure out the reason, but you could check 12 line in **heat/kypo-proxy-jump.yml** , it seems something wrong product by that. But what you get by `openstack flavor show <flavor> i get a lot of .....`, or what's the output of `openstack flavor list`, could you provide that information by update the question.